# Inviting and removing collaborators to/from project - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, multi-tenant

I am building a rails app which has projects which users (handles by Devise) can be invited to as collaborators (much like GitHub repositories and collaborators). I am struggling getting the invitations running (removing collaborators specifically). I have been following [this tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/rqjjca/creating-a-scoped-invitation-system-for-rails) to get the creation of invitations running but the tutorial does not cover revoking the invitations (removing collaborators).

I have a `projects_controller.rb` file and an `invites_controller.rb` file. The invites controller handles the creation of new invitations, which is working fine (i.e: if a user already exists, they are immediately added to a project, if a user doesn't exist, an invitation is sent to the entered email address).

How should I go about adding functionality for removing collaborators? To me, it would seam logical to use an `invites#destroy` (being that invitations are created in that controller) but then, simply deleting an invite will not revoke the user's permission to a project. And what about the users who create a project initially, they will not have an invitation at all..

Does anyone know which path I should take here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you handle collaborators to a project with a has_many association:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end
```

then you can implement `invites#destroy` to remove a user from the list of collaborators:

```
class InvitesController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    @project = Project.find params[:project_id]
    @user = User.find params[:user_to_remove]
    @project.users.delete(@user)
    # Add whatever renders or redirects you need to here
  end
end
```

Your view can use this button to remove a collaborator:

```
# Make sure @project (the project to remove from) and @user (the user to remove) are defined and non-nil
<%= link_to "Remove Collaborator", url_for(:controller => :invites, :action => :destroy, :project_id => @project.id, :user_to_remove => @user.id), :method => :delete %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `gem 'devise_invitable'` for handling invitations.
https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Correct me if i'm wrong, but as I understand it, devise_invitable is great for application-wide invitations (e.g: signing up for the app via referral), but doesn't give you much for scoped invitations..

Comment: It provides several scopes , you can override it as per your business logic